# Searching for pages in SharePoint online 2013

Tags: sharepoint-online, search, provider-hosted-app, pages

Pages are not getting filtered based on the search criteria in SharePoint Search Online 2013, Provider Hosted App. Reference for [HandleBars](http://handlebarsjs.com/)

It shows all the results. Below is the search bar and results

[image]

This is the code below

> HTML file

```
    <script id="customSearchTemplate" type="text/x-handlebars-template">

    <div class="item people-results">
        <h2>People</h2>
        <ul class="search-list">
            {{> peopleResults}}
        </ul>
        <div class="spinner hide"></div>
        <div class="message hide"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="item documents-results">
        <h2>Documents</h2>
        <ul class="search-list">
            {{> documentsResults}}
        </ul>
        <div class="spinner hide"></div>
        <div class="message hide"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="item sites-results">
        <h2>Sites</h2>
        <ul class="search-list">
            {{> sitesResults}}
        </ul>
        <div class="spinner hide"></div>
        <div class="message hide"></div>
    </div>
   <div class="item events-results">
        <h2>Events</h2>
        <ul class="search-list">
            {{> eventsResults}}
        </ul>
        <div class="spinner hide"></div>
        <div class="message hide"></div>
    </div>

</script>

<script id="peopleResultsPartialTemplate" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
    {{#each this}}
    <li>
        <a href="{{url}}">
            <span class="image">
                <img src="{{pictureUrl}}">
            </span>
            <span class="item-meta">
                <span class="item-title">{{firstName}} {{lastName}}</span>
                {{#if desc}}
                <span class="item-desc">{{desc}}</span>
                {{/if}}
                {{#if workPhone}}
                <span class="item-desc">{{workPhone}}</span>
                {{/if}}
            </span>
        </a>
    </li>
    {{/each}}
</script>

<script id="documentsResultsPartialTemplate" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
    {{#each this}}
    <li>
        <a href="{{url}}">
            <span class="image"></span>
            <span class="item-meta">
                <span class="item-title">{{title}}</span>
                <span class="item-desc">{{date}}</span>
            </span>
        </a>
    </li>
    {{/each}}
</script>

<script id="sitesResultsPartialTemplate" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
    {{#each this}}
    <li>
        <a href="{{url}}">
            <span class="image"></span>
            <span class="item-meta">
                <span class="item-title">{{title}}</span>
            </span>
        </a>
    </li>
    {{/each}}
</script>
```

> JS file

```
    var searchAgent = function (setting) {
    var controller = {
        spinnerSelector: '.spinner',
        collectionSelector: '.search-list',
        notFoundMessageSelector: '.message',
        notFoundMessage: 'No results were found for this category',
        isOpen: false,
        viewType: { isMobile: false },
        partialTemplate: function () { return this; },
        setting: {
            containerSelector: '',
            queryParams: "",
            mobileQueryParams: "",
            partialName: '',
            partialTemplateSelector: '',
            mapCallback: function () { return this; }
        },
        init: function (setting) {
            var _this = this;
            _this.setting = setting;
            var rawTemplate = $(_this.setting.partialTemplateSelector).html();
            _this.partialTemplate = Handlebars.compile(rawTemplate);
            return _this;
        },
        showResults: function (results) {
            $(this.setting.containerSelector)
            .find(this.collectionSelector)
                .html(this.partialTemplate(results));
            return this;
        },
        showNotFountMessage: function () {
            $(this.setting.containerSelector)
            .find(this.notFoundMessageSelector)
                .removeClass("hide")
                .text(this.notFoundMessage);
            return this;
        },
        hideNotFoundMessage: function () {
            $(this.setting.containerSelector)
            .find(this.notFoundMessageSelector)
                .addClass("hide")
                .text("");
            return this;
        },
        showSpinner: function () {
            $(this.setting.containerSelector)
                .find(this.spinnerSelector)
                .removeClass("hide");
            return this;
        },
        hideSpinner: function () {
            $(this.setting.containerSelector)
                .find(this.spinnerSelector)
                .addClass("hide");
            return this;
        },
        clear: function () {
            return this
                .hideNotFoundMessage()
                .hideSpinner()
                .showResults([]);
        },
        executeQuery: function (term) {
            var _this = this;

            setTimeout(function () {

                var queryUrl = "/_api/search/query?querytext='" + term + "'" + (_this.viewType.isMobile ? _this.setting.mobileQueryParams : _this.setting.queryParams);

                $.ajax({
                    async: true,
                    url: queryUrl,
                    type: 'GET',
                    headers: { 'Accept': 'application/json; odata=verbose' },
                    cache: false,
                    beforeSend: function () {
                        _this
                            .hideNotFoundMessage()
                            .showSpinner();
                    }
                })
                .done(function (data) {
                    if (!data || !data.d) {
                        return _this
                            .hideSpinner()
                            .showNotFountMessage();
                    }

                    var results = data.d.query.PrimaryQueryResult.RelevantResults.Table.Rows.results;
                    if (results.length === 0) {
                        return _this
                            .hideSpinner()
                            .showResults([])
                            .showNotFountMessage();
                    }

                    var mappedResults = $.map(results.slice(0, 4), _this.setting.mapCallback);

                    return _this
                    .hideSpinner()
                    .hideNotFoundMessage()
                    .showResults(mappedResults);

                })
                .fail(function () {

                    return _this
                        .showResults([])
                        .hideSpinner()
                        .showNotFountMessage();
                });

            }, 1);

            return _this;
        }
    };

    return controller.init(setting);
};

var Widgets = Widgets || {};
(function ($) {
    Widgets.customSearch = {
        name: "Custom Search",
        log: true,
        instance: {},
        load: function () {

            var controller = {
                templateSelector: "#customSearchTemplate",
                rootElement: {},
                searchAgents: [],
                keyHandler: {
                    inputDelay: 800,
                    lastQuery: '',
                    lastTime: -1,
                    minlength: 3
                },
                isOpen: false,
                searchUrl: '',
                template: function () { },
                viewType: { isMobile: false },
                onOpen: function () {
                    var _this = this;

                    var value = _this.getInputValue();
                    if (value.length < _this.keyHandler.minlength) {
                        return _this.clear();
                    }
                    if (value === '*') {
                        return _this.clear();
                    }

                    _this.syncAll();
                    return _this.querySuggestion(value);
                },
                onClose: function () {
                    var _this = this;
                    return _this.syncAll();
                },
                onViewTypeChanged: function () {
                    var _this = this;
                    _this.syncAll();
                    return _this.syncAll();
                },
                syncAll: function () {
                    var _this = this;
                    _this.searchAgents.forEach(function (item) {
                        item.viewType = _this.viewType;
                        item.isOpen = _this.isOpen;
                    });
                    return _this;
                },
                init: function (element) {
                    var _this = this;
                    _this.searchUrl = agn.configuration.SearchUrl;

                    _this.rootElement = element ? $(element) : $(".custom-search");

                    var rawTemplate = $(_this.templateSelector).html();
                    _this.template = Handlebars.compile(rawTemplate);

                    var peopleSearch = new searchAgent(
                        {
                            containerSelector: ".people-results",
                            queryParams: "&trimduplicates=false&rowlimit=4&selectproperties='AgnPreferredFirstName%2cAgnPreferredLastName%2cAgnDepartment%2cAccountName%2cWorkPhone%2cAgnJobTitle%2cAgnPrimaryPhoneNumber'&sourceid='" + agn.configuration.PeopleResultSourceId + "'",
                            mobileQueryParams: "&trimduplicates=false&rowlimit=2&sourceid='" + agn.configuration.PeopleResultSourceId + "'",
                            partialName: "peopleResults",
                            partialTemplateSelector: "#peopleResultsPartialTemplate",
                            mapCallback: function (value) {
                                var resultsRow = value.Cells.results;
                                var accountName = encodeURIComponent(agn.getResultValueByKey("AccountName", resultsRow));

                                var photoUrl = "/" + _spPageContextInfo.layoutsUrl + "/userphoto.aspx?size=M&accountname=" + accountName;
                                return {
                                    url: agn.configuration.viewProfileUrl + '?accountname=' + accountName,
                                    pictureUrl: photoUrl,                                   
                                    firstName: agn.getResultValueByKey("AgnPreferredFirstName", resultsRow),
                                    lastName: agn.getResultValueByKey("AgnPreferredLastName", resultsRow),
                                    desc: agn.getResultValueByKey("AgnJobTitle", resultsRow),
                                    workPhone: agn.getResultValueByKey("AgnPrimaryPhoneNumber", resultsRow)
                                };
                            }
                        });

                    peopleSearch.viewType = _this.viewType;
                    _this.searchAgents.push(peopleSearch);
                    Handlebars.registerPartial(peopleSearch.setting.partialName, peopleSearch.partialTemplate);

                    var documentSearch = new searchAgent(
                        {
                            containerSelector: ".documents-results",
                            queryParams: "&trimduplicates=false&rowlimit=4&sourceid='" + agn.configuration.DocumentsResultSourceId + "'",
                            mobileQueryParams: "&trimduplicates=false&rowlimit=2&sourceid='" + agn.configuration.DocumentsResultSourceId + "'",
                            partialName: "documentsResults",
                            partialTemplateSelector: "#documentsResultsPartialTemplate",
                            mapCallback: function (value) {
                                var resultsRow = value.Cells.results;
                                return {
                                    url: agn.getResultValueByKey("Path", resultsRow),
                                    title: agn.getResultValueByKey("Title", resultsRow),
                                    date: $.format.date(new Date(agn.getResultValueByKey("LastModifiedTime", resultsRow)), 'MM.dd.yy')
                                };
                            }
                        });

                    documentSearch.viewType = _this.viewType;
                    _this.searchAgents.push(documentSearch);
                    Handlebars.registerPartial(documentSearch.setting.partialName, documentSearch.partialTemplate);

                    var sitesSearch = new searchAgent(
                        {
                            containerSelector: ".sites-results",
                            queryParams: "&trimduplicates=false&rowlimit=4&sourceid='" + agn.configuration.SitesResultSourceId + "'",
                            mobileQueryParams: "&trimduplicates=false&rowlimit=2&sourceid='" + agn.configuration.SitesResultSourceId + "'",
                            partialName: "sitesResults",
                            partialTemplateSelector: "#sitesResultsPartialTemplate",
                            mapCallback: function (value) {
                                var resultsRow = value.Cells.results;
                                return {
                                    url: agn.getResultValueByKey("Path", resultsRow),
                                    title: agn.getResultValueByKey("Title", resultsRow)
                                };
                            }
                        });

                    sitesSearch.viewType = _this.viewType;
                    _this.searchAgents.push(sitesSearch);
                    Handlebars.registerPartial(sitesSearch.setting.partialName, sitesSearch.partialTemplate);


                    /*var eventsSearch = new searchAgent(
                        {
                            containerSelector: ".events-results",
                            queryParams: "&trimduplicates=false&rowlimit=4&selectproperties='Path%2cUrl%2cTitle%2cEventDateOWSDATE%2cRefinableDate00'&sourceid='" + agn.configuration.EventsResultSourceId + "'",
                            mobileQueryParams: "&trimduplicates=false&rowlimit=4&selectproperties='Path%2cUrl%2cTitle%2cEventDateOWSDATE%2cRefinableDate00'&sourceid='" + agn.configuration.EventsResultSourceId + "'",
                            partialName: "eventsResults",
                            partialTemplateSelector: "#eventsResultsPartialTemplate",
                            mapCallback: function (value) {
                                var resultsRow = value.Cells.results;
                                return {
                                    url: encodeURI(agn.getResultValueByKey("Path", resultsRow)),
                                    title: agn.getResultValueByKey("Title", resultsRow),
                                    date: $.format.date(new Date(agn.getResultValueByKey("RefinableDate00", resultsRow)), 'MM.dd.yy')
                                };
                            }
                        });

                    eventsSearch.viewType = _this.viewType;
                    _this.searchAgents.push(eventsSearch);
                    Handlebars.registerPartial(eventsSearch.setting.partialName, eventsSearch.partialTemplate); */

                    _this.rootElement.find('.search-flyout').html(_this.template({}));

                    _this.rootElement.find("#cancelSearch").off()
                        .on("mousedown touchstart", function () {
                            _this.cancelSearch();
                        })
                        .on("click", function () {
                            _this.cancelSearch();
                        });

                    _this.rootElement.find("#performSearch").off()
                        .on("click", function () {
                            _this.peformSearch();
                    });

                    _this.rootElement.find("#headerInput").off()
                        .on("keyup", function (event) {
                            var invalidKeys = [9, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 91, 92, 112, 113, 114, 115, 116, 117, 118, 119, 120, 121, 122, 123, 144, 145];
                            if (event.which === 0) {
                                return;
                            }
                            if (event.which === 13) { // enter
                                return _this.peformSearch();
                            }
                            if (event.which === 27) {
                                return _this.cancelSearch();
                            }
                            if (event.which === 8) {
                                if (_this.getInputValue() === '*' || _this.getInputValue() === '') {
                                    if (_this.isOpen) {
                                        return _this.close();
                                    }
                                    return;
                                }
                            }

                            if (invalidKeys.indexOf(event.which) >= 0) {
                                return;
                            }

                            if (!_this.isOpen) {
                                _this.open();
                            }

                            _this.keyHandler.lastTime = new Date().getTime();

                            setTimeout(function () {
                                var currentTime = new Date().getTime();
                                var dif = currentTime - _this.keyHandler.lastTime;
                                if (dif < _this.keyHandler.inputDelay || !_this.isOpen) {
                                    return;
                                }
                                var value = _this.getInputValue();
                                if (value.length < _this.keyHandler.minlength) {
                                    return;
                                }
                                if (value === '*') {
                                    return;
                                }
                                return _this.querySuggestion(value);
                            }, _this.keyHandler.inputDelay);
                        });

                    $('body').on('mousedown touchstart', function (event) {
                        if ($(event.target).closest(_this.rootElement).length === 0) {
                            return _this.close();
                        }
                    });                 

                    _this.rootElement.on("onOpen", function (event) {
                        return _this.onOpen(event);
                    });

                    _this.rootElement.on("onClose", function (event) {
                        return _this.onClose(event);
                    });

                    _this.rootElement.on("onViewTypeChanged", function (event) {
                        return _this.onViewTypeChanged(event);
                    });

                    pTracer.end('customSearch');
                    return _this;
                },
                peformSearch: function () {
                    var _this = this;
                    var url = _this.searchUrl + '#k=' + _this.getInputValue();
                    window.location.replace(url);
                    return this;
                },
                getInputValue: function () {
                    var _this = this;
                    return _this.rootElement.find("#headerInput").val() + '*';
                },
                cancelSearch: function () {
                    var _this = this;
                    _this.rootElement.find("#headerInput").val("");

                    _this.searchAgents.forEach(function (item) {
                        item.clear();
                    });
                    return _this.close();
                },
                querySuggestion: function (term) {
                    var _this = this;
                    _this.searchAgents.forEach(function (item) {
                        item.executeQuery(term);
                    });

                    return _this;
                },
                clear: function () {
                    var _this = this;
                    _this.searchAgents.forEach(function (item) {
                        item.clear();
                    });

                    return _this;
                },
                open: function () {
                    var _this = this;
                    if (!_this.isOpen) {
                        _this.isOpen = true;
                    }
                    if (!_this.rootElement.find("div.input").is(".focus")) {
                        _this.rootElement.find("div.input").addClass("focus");
                    }

                    _this.rootElement.trigger("onOpen");

                    return _this;
                },
                close: function () {
                    var _this = this;
                    if (_this.isOpen) {
                        _this.isOpen = false;
                    }
                    if (_this.rootElement.find("div.input").is(".focus")) {
                        _this.rootElement.find("div.input").removeClass("focus");
                    }
                    _this.rootElement.trigger("onClose");
                    return _this;
                }
            };

            this.instance = controller;

            return controller.init(this.container);
        }
    };
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: Can you explain what your `searchAgent` does?

Comment: could you explain `Handlebars`?

Comment: Your question is not clear. Add more description

Comment: You didn't specify query text anywhere. Also, you didn't include any code that executes a search.

Comment: @Snickbrak - Handlebars ref is added

Comment: The registering of your partial `mypageResults` seems incorrect. Have a look at the documentation: http://handlebarsjs.com/partials.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found It! Issue was with Source ID's thats being used. In order to create a custom search we have to create a resultSource with {searchTerm} in it. This allows to search the resultsource based on the string we enter in the search.

Answer (score 1):

Could you just change `containerSelector: ".page-results"` to `containerSelector: ".item page-results"` in above code and try?

Also, I am not sure `{{> mypageResults}}` where you using this in js code? or have you mistype it in `partialName` in js code?